# Como inciar um processamento no spring-boot após injetar todos os beans e antes de começar a ouvir eventos externos?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estou criando uma aplicação em Spring-Boot que para mim é crítico ela recuperar seu ponto de processamento anterior *antes* de começar a receber novas requisições.

Para tal, eu tenho uma tabela chamada `PROCESSOS` que guarda um ID único, o seu estágio de processamento (enfileirado, processando, concluído, etc), um ponteiro para onde está o dado sendo processado e outras informações sem relevância pra essa questão.

Para recuperar os processos que pararam no meio do caminho, eu faço a seguinte consulta no método `List<Integer> recuperaBreakpoint()`:

```sql
SELECT id, 1 as type
FROM PROCESSOS
WHERE estagio_id != 'QUEUED' AND
    (estagio_id NOT LIKE 'FINISHED%' COLLATE NOCASE AND
    estagio_id NOT LIKE 'FAILED%' COLLATE NOCASE AND
    estagio_id NOT LIKE 'CANCELED%' COLLATE NOCASE)
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 2 as type 
FROM PROCESSOS  WHERE estagio_id = 'QUEUED'
ORDER BY type, id
```

E ela me retorna o que eu quero na ordem que eu quero:

- o retorno contém todos os processos não terminados/cancelados/falhos
- priorizo no retorno quem já começou algum processamento
- só então coloco os processos que foram apenas enfileirados (`QUEUED`), porém não sofreram nenhum processo ainda

Em tese, após recuperar esses processos, seria só delegar a alguma thread executora disponível (ou colocar no pool de processos a serem executados, no caso de não ter executores disponíveis). Eu faço isso através da função `void executaProcesso(int idProcesso)`, que vai se encarregar de delegar aos exeutores/enfileirar as requisições perfeitamente.

A questão é:

- Como, em Spring-Boot, faço para resgatar esses valores e dar continuidade ao processo no início da aplicação porém antes de começar a responder requisições externas?
- Em outras palavras, como fazer `recuperaBreakpoint().stream().forEachOrdered(this::executaProcesso)` assim que o Spring-Boot estiver pronto pra rodar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fala Jefferson,

Você pode realizar isso utilizando a annotation [@EventListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/EventListener.html), ela atua como listener para executar certo método dependendo do evento de inicialização gerado.

Os eventos derivam de [ApplicationEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationEvent.html?is-external=true), podendo ser utilizados os [SpringApplicationEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/event/SpringApplicationEvent.html) ou [ApplicationContextEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ApplicationContextEvent.html)

Basta você colocar a annotation no método e indicar o evento em que gostaria de executar o código:

```
@EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
public void warmup() {
    System.out.println("Código executado logo após a aplicação ser startada");
}
```

Eu recomendo você utilizar o evento [ContextRefreshedEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextRefreshedEvent.html) **porque ele é executado antes da aplicação começar a aceitar requests** (os request passam a ser aceitos após a emissão do evento [ApplicationReadyEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/event/ApplicationReadyEvent.html)).

Comment: Eu estava quase respondendo algo próximo disso, mas tinha me esquecido. Então apareceu sua resposta, consideravelmente mais bem embasada daquela que eu tinha em mente. Muito obrigado por responder, e muito obrigado em especial pelas referências